# IBAction Lags When Button Pressed

Tags: iphone

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` in it. I add a `UIView` as a subview on top of that. When I press one of the `UIButton`s on the subview, there is a noticeable lag. How do I make it faster?

See video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWy6NrZUeqA&feature=youtu.be

```
- (IBAction)tweetThat:(id)sender {
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.socialMediaView animated:YES];

    dispatch_queue_t queueOne=dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_sync(queueOne, ^{
        NSString *tweetBody=@"BLABLABLATweet";

        if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
        {
            TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
            [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
            [tweetSheet setInitialText:tweetBody];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.controllerView animated:YES];
                [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];
            });
        }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your dispatch_sync to dispatch_async. what is the point of dispatching to the background if you are going to lock up the UI until it returns.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the dispatch method you tried above, but with a few changes. It has really made the experience a lot better. "loadingView" is as named, just a loading view that displays before the tweet view comes up.

```
    loadingView.hidden = NO;
    [loadingView setNeedsDisplay];
    if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
    {
        double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            TWTweetComposeViewController *tweet = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc]init];
            [tweet setInitialText:@"I'm using a new app called TickTalk to help my speaking cadence. Check it out!"];
            [tweet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ticktalkapp.com"]];
            TWTweetComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler
            completionHandler =
            ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
                switch (result)
                {
                    case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                        NSLog(@"Twitter Result: canceled");
                        break;
                    case TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                        NSLog(@"Twitter Result: sent");
                        break;
                    default:
                        NSLog(@"Twitter Result: default");
                        break;
                }
                loadingView.hidden = YES;
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            };
            [tweet setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
            [self presentModalViewController:tweet animated:YES];
        });
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Your device is not setup to tweet" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        loadingView.hidden = YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The lag is from `TWTweetComposeViewController`. There is nothing you can do about it because its a system optimization. You'll probably notice the second and third times you hit the button the lag it gone.

Comment: Yes, I did notice that it speeds up the next time. But why does the MBProgressHUD also get delayed? The MBProgressHUD is the first thing called on the main thread, while the TWTweetComposeViewController is alloc'd and init'd on a background thread. Also, what does "system optimization" mean?

Comment: That I'm not sure of. I don't do a lot with `dispatch_queue`s myself and when I do I normally use `performSelectorOnBackgroundThread` as a set and forget kind of method. As far as system optimization I'm saying whatever lag is there because of `TWTweetComposeViewController` I don't think you can fix it. Apple has to.